# How to uninstall Canon IJ Network Scanner?

Tags: macos, canon

I got rid of a Canon all-in-one printer/scanner, but how can I get rid of the `Canon IJ Network Scanner` (and other Canon softwares that might have been installed) on my Mac? It is not showing in `Applications`.

Answer (score 4):

Additional Canon software is installed in `/Library/Printers/Canon`. You can use <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> in Finder to open a Finder window for that folder.

Answer (score -4):

I would use a great mac app called App Cleaner, you just drag the icon to the window and it deletes all files associated with it.

https://www.google.com/#q=app+cleaner

Comment: It's highly unlikely an app cleaner will remove that printer support file. Have you run that tool on this type of program item or should this be removed as a "lmgtfy" type suggestion that doesn't really address the problem at hand.